# How can I identify HitLeap traffic?

Tags: javascript

I operate a media website that has advert integration. Lately we have been getting a lot of people abusing this by using traffic exchange on their uploads to gain false revenues. The most popular would probably be a HitLeap using the HitLeap Viewer application.

I am curious if there are any practices I could use to identify and redirect HitLeap traffic?

Currently I am trying to solo it out from other traffic with limited success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
var is_hitleap = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('hitleap-viewer') > -1;
if(is_chrome){
document.write('This is chrome!');
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

The majority of hitleap traffic can be identified with user agent = 'HitLeap Viewer  2.8'

The exchange you're integrated with should be responsible for filtering out this traffic.

Comment: Does that mean `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('hitleap-viewer') > -1` suffices after the hyphen was removed?

Comment: it's probably easiest to use just "hitleap" as the string to pass to indexOf and that would work fine.  In a scan of 300 million ads the other day, I found no other user agents that had the string "hitleap" in them other than "HitLeap Viewer 2.8", so I don't think there's risk of accidentally filtering out legitimate traffic by just using "hitleap"

Comment: @twoody Who would add or modify "hitleap" as it's own user-agent by accident? Nobody, you're looking only the header called User-Agent, so yes, it's impossible that you'll find that string if you don't use that software. U don't have to scan million views to figure it. If you look at url or body would be totally different, but is not.

Comment: Premium users of Hitleap would hide it's userAgent and probably the referrer.